# Vertically centered card between header and footer

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Trying to get the card vertically centered between header and footer, and the card must be in second floor since header and footer are in the first floor, to avoid responsive wrong behavior, like over impression of the card over header and footer.
This is my current situation: [LINK](https://unknow.tv/prova5.php)
Im newer of bootstrap, every suggestion it is appreciate.

```css
.card {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Added */
  float: none;
  /* Added */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* Added */
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 55px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #343A40;
  vertical-align: middle;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">




<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="/img/unknow16.png" height="32" alt="Unknow TV">
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">  </span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign In <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacts</a>
      </li>


    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>

<br><br>
<div class=" w-50 card ">
  <div class="card-header">
    Login
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Username</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter username">
        <!-- <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>-->
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <!-- <div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
  </div>-->
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>


<footer class="footer text-center">
  <p> </p>
  <div class="container ">
    <span class="text-muted">
© <script type="text/javascript">
document.write("2018 - "+ new Date().getFullYear());
</script>2018 - 2020 Weyland-Yutani</span>
  </div>
  <p></p>
</footer>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: So you want the center of it in the middle of the page?

Comment: yes, trying to edit .cent css I think

Comment: The header, has a dropdown menu, that shift all the content below, maybe the best behavior would be set that the dropdown menu override content instead shift it.

Comment: Ok my answer should stop it from moving the content below

Comment: Post the code in the question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class=" w-50 card ">
 <div class="card-header">
    Login
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
     <form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Username</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter username">
   <!-- <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>-->
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
 <!-- <div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
  </div>-->
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card { <!-- Delete existing card code -->
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

This should fix it exactly in the center just delete the existing code to fix it horizontally center to remove some problems.

Comment: Thanks you @aparep7474, I upgraded it as your suggestion: www.unknow.tv/prova6.php, the only issue now is that the dropdown menu of the header is in a second floor instead the card is first, so with some resolutions,  the card is over the dropdown

Comment: So the problem now is that the card is over the dropdown right? Do you just want it the other way dropdown over card

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new element in the DOM, make the card a child of it and add the following styles, using [Flexbox Model](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) this is easily achievable.

Of course, remove the `br` tags as they are not needed.

```css
.card-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: calc(100% - 110px);
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="w-50 card">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

thanks to suggestions, now the card is centered, the dropdown never shift content anymore, but with less resolutions, the card is over the haeder, I need to place it in second floor and the header one the first one

[image: Current wrong behaviour]

Comment: To fix that error just add the styling ```z-index: 1``` to the nav and ```z-index: -1``` to the card that should do it. I was confused because I didn't have the same view as you.

Comment: Great, fixed, thank you!

Comment: no problem pin me if you need anymore help

Comment: Thank you! actually the issue is that z-index avoid me to type input form @aparep7474